# Custom module in drupal 8, tab not created in admin section

Tags: drupal-8

I created custom module in Drupal 8. This module should create tab in admin/content. But unfortunately tab does not display in admin/content section. While I can able to access my module. Link to access my module 'localhost/demo/admin/content/book'

Here is my code:-
book.routing.yml

```
# book.routing.yml snippet
book.admin:
  path: '/admin/content/book'
  defaults:
     _form: '\Drupal\book\Form\bookForm'
    _title: 'BOOKS'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'book access'
```

book.links.menu.yml

```
# book.links.menu.yml snippet
book.admin:
  route_name: book.admin
  title: BOOKS
  base_route: system.admin_content
```

For more information attaching screenshot, where I want tab

 Expecting this one 
 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should rename the file to

> book.links.task.yml

because what you want is a "task" of the content instead of a real menu link. Here's a great explanation and guide how to create custom modules:

http://www.sitepoint.com/build-drupal-8-module-routing-controllers-menu-links/

Note that some of his file namings are outdated (e.g. "menu_links"), but the general idea/structure of a module is still well explained.